# Undefined index in php inside selected drop down

Tags: php

[this is the undefined error that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTFJv.png)

the update is working. but after i clicked the submit button, the selected dropdown gave me this error.

```
$row=array();
if (isset($_GET['typeid'])) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicletype WHERE id_vehicleType=" . $_GET['typeid'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
    // update record

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['idtype']);
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['type']);
    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['status']);
    $update = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['idinfostaf']);

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE vehicletype SET vehicle_Type='$type', status_vehicleType='$status', updateby_vehicleType='$update' WHERE id_vehicleType=".$id);

    if ($result) {

        $success = "Record updated successfully!";
    }
    else {
       $error = "Error updating record...";
    }
}
```

i put the php code and html on the same page..below is the html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Choose Vehicle Type Status</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="status" required class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($row['status_vehicleType'])){ echo $row['status_vehicleType'];} ?>">
   <option value="">Select Vehicle Type</option>
   <option
            value="1" <?php if ($row['status_vehicleType']==$_GET["typeid"]) { echo  'selected="selected"' ;} ?> >Enabled</option>
        <option
            value="0" <?php if ($row['status_vehicleType']== $_GET["typeid"]) { echo  'selected="selected"' ;} ?> >Disabled</option>
    </select>

    <hr>

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit </button>

<span class="text-success"><?php if (isset($success)) { echo $success; } ?></span>
<span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?></span>
```

i used the typeid to carry the values.

Comment: I can't seem to locate that `status_vehicleBrand`

Comment: sorry, i gave the wrong picture, but it still gave me the same error. undefined index status_vehicleType.

Comment: ive changed the image..

Comment: Try echoing first just `$row['status_vehicleType']`

Comment: i tried it, before i clicked the update update, the value is correct. but after i click on the update button, the same error appeared.

Comment: Try adding `if(isset($row['status_vehicleType']))` in the `<option>`

Comment: the update is succesfull but the dropdown gave me the error.

Comment: <option
                value="1" <?php if (isset ($row['status_vehicleType'])){ if ($row['status_vehicleType']==$_GET["typeid"]) { echo  'selected="selected"' ;} } ?> >Enabled</option>

Comment: i did it like this. the error is gone. but the selected does not work.

Comment: @Swellar thanks. it worked. i used this  <option value="1" <?php if(isset($row['status_vehicleBrand'])){ if($row['status_vehicleBrand']==1){?>selected<?php }} ?>>Enabled</option>

Comment: Guess I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select value="<?php if(isset($row['status_vehicleType'])){ echo $row['status_vehicleType'];} ?>">
   <option value="">Select Vehicle Type</option>
   <option value="1" <?php 
                        if(isset($row['status_vehicleBrand'])) {
                            if ($row['status_vehicleBrand']==$_GET["typeid"]) { 
                                echo 'Selected' ;
                            }
                        } ?> >Enabled</option>
   <option value="0" <?php 
                        if(isset($row['status_vehicleBrand'])) {
                            if ($row['status_vehicleBrand']==$_GET["typeid"]) { 
                                echo 'Selected' ;
                            }
                        } ?> >Disabled</option>
 </select>
```